# Eclipse plugin for running some cvs commands

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, cvs

Is there an eclipse plugin that allows sending cvs commands?

For example i want to list a specific users's commits and i need to run

```
cvs log -t -w myuser
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CVS team provider was integrated with Eclipse. All user actions like commit, checkout etc via menu items or button are converted to corresponding CVS commands and sent to CVS server.

A [CVS tools](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/cvs-tools#.UylupaaoJk8) plugin was discontinued which performs advanced CVS operations.

You can execute CVS command in an external command interpreter(**cmd** on windows **terminal** on Linux).

You can install and integrate command interpreter plugin inside eclipse [see here](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/remote-system-explorer-ssh-telnet-ftp-and-dstore-protocols).